# how to make my slideshow content be responsive?

Tags: html, css

i just stack into this part, my other component in my web is responsive but idont know to make my content slideshow or maybe the container be responsive, if someone can help please answer my question and guide me

Comment: Please provide codes, you can use media queries for that

Comment: You should provide some code and Please, tell us what have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome, julianto. As is, your question is too broad and unclear. How about you include a snippet of the relevant (and only the relevant) code so we can see what you have right now. Then try to explain what exactly the issue is. The resizing of the images? Making it work with touch instead of mouse interaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a presentation with Reveal.js

It is an html/css/JavaScript based presentation framework. It has many features that a conventional presentation cannot provide and has all the features from the web world

Comment: We don't even fully understand the question yet but we're already throwing frameworks at it? I'm not sure this is a good idea.